# Batch Text File Encryption

Tags: batch-file, encryption

I am working on a small program the purpose of the program  is to first collect documents on a computer, then transfer a copy of the documents to an alternate folder, then encrypt the documents. While I have so far figured out how to copy all the documents, into a single folder (directory path D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE) I have no managed to find a way to encrypt the documents once they reach the folder. As I have no real idea what I am doing, I attempted certuil encode D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE, but with no luck. Does anyone have any advice for how I could complete this task?

Note- It is acceptable if the contents of the files are simply converted into Hexadecimal or otherwise changed from plain text.

```
 @echo off
 color a
 ipconfig > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\ip.txt
 net user > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\users.txt
 tasklist > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\tasks.txt
 systeminfo > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\info.txt
 driverquery > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\drivers.txt
 xcopy /J /Z /Y /G /Q "%userprofile%\Documents"  D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\
 certutil -encode D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\
 cls
 color a

 timeout 5
```

I would like to encript the documents within D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE

Comment: Show your actual code that is not working (edit your question, and use the help links to format your code as code.) CERTUTIL is extremely easy to use.

Answer (score 3):

Use `certutil -encode -?` to get help on the syntax and options.

CERTUTIL -encode can only process one file at a time; you must specify a specific file for both input and output.

Since you only want the encoded versions in your destination, it makes more sense to encode from the original source directory directly into your destination directory, so there is no need for XCOPY.

Use a simple FOR loop to iterate the files in your source. The `%%~nxF` yields the file name and extension, without the path information, which is needed for your destination.

```
@echo off
color a
ipconfig > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\ip.txt
net user > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\users.txt
tasklist > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\tasks.txt
systeminfo > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\info.txt
driverquery > D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\drivers.txt
for %%F in ("%userprofile%\Documents\*") do certutil -encode "%%F" "D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE\%%~nxF"
```

The code looks a lot cleaner if you PUSHD to your destination first

```
@echo off
color a
pushd D:\DONOTDELETE\DONOTDELETE
ipconfig > ip.txt
net user > users.txt
tasklist > tasks.txt
systeminfo > info.txt
driverquery > drivers.txt
cd DONOTDELETE
for %%F in ("%userprofile%\Documents\*") do certutil -encode "%%F" "%%~nxF"
popd
```